# Why isnt the acceleration of the first system the same as the acceleration of the second system from a conceptual standpoint?

Tags: kinematics

I am having a hard time understanding conceptually why the acceleration of the system is different in the first two cases. Specifically, how could block A possibly know whether block B is a block or just someone pulling on it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Observation #1: The first system has a mass of 300lb.  The second system has a mass of 200lb.

The same net force on each system will create accelerations with different magnitudes.

Observation #2: Looking at the first system with the unequal weights, we expect the system to allow the greater mass to accelerate downward and the lighter mass to accelerate upward.

If the lighter mass is accelerating upward, it must be pulled by a tension that exceeds 100lb of force.  But the second system has a tension of exactly 100lb of force.  So again the systems are not identical.

Comment: woah, that is a very smart way of thinking about it. thank you very much. wish my physics prof was as good at explaining this as u are!